# Progression to 3NF

Tags: normalization, relational-theory

my relation is:

```
H = {A,B,C,D,E}
A -> C
{A,D} -> E
B -> C
{B,D} -> E
C -> B
E -> C
```

I have to convert this relation to 3NF. 
The candidate key : `{A,D}`

First step is minimalization. In minimalization i can drop `{A,D} -> E` out of fds.

```
H = {A,B,C,D,E}
A -> C
B -> C
{B,D} -> E
C -> B
E -> C
```

Decomposition:

```
H1 = {A,C} with key A
H2 = {B,C} with key B and FD: B -> C
H3 = {B,D,E} with key {B,D}
H4 = {C,B}  with key C and FD: C ->B
H5 = {E,C} with key E
H6 = {A,D} with key A // added because one relation must contains key
```

I got confused when i saw H2 and H4. They looks almost similar. So, should merge both into one ? To get one relation:

`H2 = {B,C} with keys {B},{C} and fds: B -> C, C -> B`?

Since relations `H1` and `H6` have the same key, can i merge them to?

Thanks for help

Comment: The only candidade key is `AD`, not `AC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H2` and `H4` are exactly the same relation, since the order of the attributes does not matter. In general the synthesis algorithm requires that, after the first phase, you should remove all the relations contained in others. So, the answer to the first question is yes, and of course the relation `{B, C}` has two dependencies `B → C` and `C → B`, and two candidate keys, `B` and `C`.

On the other hand, `H1` and `H6` are different relations, which should not be merged together (and, moreover, they *do not have* the same keys, since `H1` has key `A`, while `H6` has key `{A, D}` (and no dependencies)).